# go back to the same state on history.js

Tags: browser-history, history.js

on my single page app i have a page that the user have a select box and the data can changed according to the option the user selected.

when the data changed, i'm pushing a new state to the history

```
History.pushState({'id':params.id}, 'activity', '?activity');
```

the push works fine, the problem is when i hit 'back' the history detect that the previous state is the same ('activity') so the back doesn't work. but the data is different and i want the plugin to reload the same page but with the previous data.

Comment: maybe someone know? i can't find a solution for that anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This wasn't an issue about same state. I forgot to add preventDefault to the link that change the state.